# ASP.NET C# Running Concurrent Build Profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

I want to use a slightly different calculation method in my project, if I am running in test vs. final mode. But I want to deploy the two build profiles - test and final concurrently. They both live on same web server - IIS - such that the user can run either one or the other or both in two different browser tabs, and can compare the two results.

Is there a way I can do this by #if with multiple build profiles? How do I deploy? Thanks.

```
#if TEST
     int res = calcTest(x1, x2, x3);
#else
     int res = calcFinal(x1, x4);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I need to create two different projects on the IIS end and use different port numbers.I used the below and deployed separately.

```
        Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        int port = uri.Port;
```

Comment: Used a different port number